# ASP.NET Core - Validation for current value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a modal window that is used to register or edit new objects (`Machines`).

These `Machines` have a property called `NumDevices` (Number of devices).

For the purpose of this project I have to validate that the input wrote for this property **can't be less that the current value**

I currently have this:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="NumDevices" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
              <input id="NumDevices" asp-for="NumDevices" class="form-control" />
              <span asp-validation-for="NumDevices"  class="text-danger"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I would like to validate that:

- The new value inserted is equal or greater than the original value
- Show an ErrorMessage indicating that the inserted value can't be less than original value

I'm looking on how can I capture the current value and add this modifications.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Will update any progress!

Comment: Is this ASP.NET Core or ASP.NET Web Form?

Comment: It is for ASP.NET Core :)

Comment: `CompareValidator` is ASP.NET Web Form server control. You cannot use in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: ... Ok, this is bad. I'll look for a substitute for ASP.NET Core and re-edit the question after research

Comment: In ASP .net Core WebForms have been deprecated in favor of Razor and MVC which is lighter. Said that, Razor combines perfectly with client-side frameworks like Angular JS, you can use the Angular JS validators to achieve what you want. Take a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp

Comment: @Gusman Thanks, I have read it. It helps but it does not show how to capture current data to compare with the new data entry. Will keep looking.